# Choosing lock granularity

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, locking, mutex

I was testing out performance for several basic mutex implementations to try to get a feel for what solution would work best.
The operations are simple, a vector of 5 ints is constantly being overwritten by 4 threads, one adding, one subtracting, and two others doing the same but in reverse order.

I'm having some trouble interpreting the results though:

3.3 seconds for serialized single thread for the entire workload

2.1 if I use one lock for each of the individual vector slots (so 5 locks)

1.6 if I just use one big lock for any writing to the vector access

0.33 if I don't use locks (this naturally gives bad results)

Shouldn't the individual locks be faster than just using one big one?

As requested :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//Guard automatically encapsulates a join so that upper layer operations aren't compromised and the main programmer doesn't need to worry about joining on every exit

class Guard {
    std::thread& t;
public:
    explicit Guard(std::thread & t_) : t(t_) {};
    ~Guard() {
        if (t.joinable()) {
            t.join();                              //join waits so no need to check timers and such
        }
    }
    Guard(Guard const &) = delete;                 //prevents automatic reassignment
    Guard & operator = (Guard const &) = delete;   //prevents copying

};

void idfunc(int x, std::string input) {

    std::cout << input << x << std::hex << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

#define CONSTOP 1000000
#define SIZEBUFFER 5
bool s1, s2, s3, s4 = false;
float d1, d2, d3, d4 = 0.0f;
std::vector<std::mutex> mm(SIZEBUFFER);
std::mutex singlelock;

void fs_up(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSTOP; i++) {
        singlelock.lock();
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]++;
        singlelock.unlock();
    }
    s1 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d1 = diff.count();
}


void fs_down(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSTOP; i++) {
        singlelock.lock();
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]--;
        singlelock.unlock();
    }
    s2 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d2 = diff.count();
}

void fs_downright(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = CONSTOP - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        singlelock.lock();
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]--;
        singlelock.unlock();
    }
    s3 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d3 = diff.count();
}

void fs_upright(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = CONSTOP - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        singlelock.lock();
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]++;
        singlelock.unlock();
    }
    s4 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d4 = diff.count();
}

void f_upno(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSTOP; i++) {
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]++;
    }
    s1 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d1 = diff.count();
}


void f_downno(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSTOP; i++) {
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]--;
    }
    s2 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d2 = diff.count();
}

void f_downrightno(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = CONSTOP - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]--;
    }
    s3 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d3 = diff.count();
}

void f_uprightno(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = CONSTOP - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]++;
    }
    s4 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d4 = diff.count();
}



void f_up(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSTOP; i++){
        mm[i%SIZEBUFFER].lock();
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]++;
        mm[i%SIZEBUFFER].unlock();
    }
    s1 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d1 = diff.count();
}


void f_down(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSTOP; i++) {
        mm[i%SIZEBUFFER].lock();
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]--;
        mm[i%SIZEBUFFER].unlock();
    }
    s2 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d2 = diff.count();
}

void f_downright(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = CONSTOP - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        mm[i%SIZEBUFFER].lock();
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]--;
        mm[i%SIZEBUFFER].unlock();
    }
    s3 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d3 = diff.count();
}

void f_upright(std::vector<int>& input) {

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = CONSTOP - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
        mm[i%SIZEBUFFER].lock();
        input[i%SIZEBUFFER]++;
        mm[i%SIZEBUFFER].unlock();
    }
    s4 = true;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    d4 = diff.count();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> buffer(SIZEBUFFER, 0);
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    f_up(buffer);
    f_down(buffer);
    f_downright(buffer);
    f_upright(buffer);



    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    std::cout << "Benchmark is: " << diff.count() << std::endl;

    int num = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    /*for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        std::thread t(idfunc, 0, "ThreadID is: ");
        Guard g(t);
        //code safe from here on out
    }*/
    std::thread t1(f_up, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* g1  = new Guard(t1);
    std::thread t2(f_down, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* g2 = new Guard(t2);
    std::thread t3(f_downright, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* g3 = new Guard(t3);
    std::thread t4(f_upright, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* g4 = new Guard(t4);


    while (true) {  
        break;          // to reuse if main thread is supposed to do something besides waiting
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        if (s1 && s2 && s3 && s4) {  
            break;
        }
    }


    delete g1;
    delete g2;
    delete g3;
    delete g4;

    std::cout << "Individual Locks Execution lasted: " << std::max({ d1,d2,d3,d4 }) << "(" << d1 << " " << d2 << " " << d3 << " " << d4 << ")" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    for (auto cell : buffer) {
        std::cout << std::dec << cell << std::endl;
    }



    std::thread t11(fs_up, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* g11 = new Guard(t11);
    std::thread t12(fs_down, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* g12 = new Guard(t12);
    std::thread t13(fs_downright, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* g13 = new Guard(t13);
    std::thread t14(fs_upright, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* g14 = new Guard(t14);



    while (true) {
        break;          // to reuse if main thread is supposed to do something besides waiting
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        if (s1 && s2 && s3 && s4) {
            break;
        }
    }


    delete g11;
    delete g12;
    delete g13;
    delete g14;

    std::cout << "One Lock Execution lasted: " << std::max({ d1,d2,d3,d4 }) << "(" << d1 << " " << d2 << " " << d3 << " " << d4 << ")" << std::endl;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    for (auto cell : buffer) {
        std::cout << std::dec << cell << std::endl;
    }


    std::thread tn1(f_upno, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* gn1 = new Guard(tn1);
    std::thread tn2(f_downno, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* gn2 = new Guard(tn2);
    std::thread tn3(f_downrightno, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* gn3 = new Guard(tn3);
    std::thread tn4(f_uprightno, std::ref(buffer));
    Guard* gn4 = new Guard(tn4);



    while (true) {
        break;          // to reuse if main thread is supposed to do something besides waiting
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        if (s1 && s2 && s3 && s4) {
            break;
        }
    }


    delete gn1;
    delete gn2;
    delete gn3;
    delete gn4;

    std::cout << "No Sync Execution lasted: " << std::max({ d1,d2,d3,d4 }) << "(" << d1 << " " << d2 << " " << d3 << " " << d4 << ")" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    for (auto cell : buffer) {
        std::cout << std::dec << cell << std::endl;
    }


    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

}
```

Basically I created functions for each of the tests which are run in order. All threads are deleted and remade for each phase. I am using the Microsoft C/C++ Compiler that comes which VS2017, so at least c++11 is supported. I didn't change any of the default compilation lines but I did notice that optimization is turned off. Anyway all the compiler options:

/permissive- /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\ThreadingTester.pch" /diagnostics:classic

Comment: Please share the benchmark's source code as well as any input data. The compiler, compiler version and compilation flags may also be relevant.

Comment: it completely depends on the access patterns. I guess one could easily come up with a scenario where a single lock for the whole vector is faster than locking individual elements as well as vice versa. Without seeing the code it is impossible to interpret your results

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux added the stuff you requested.

Comment: @tobi303 I added the code. I guess my problem is that looking at it, it makes more sense to me at least that it would be faster with individual unit locks instead of a big one.

Comment: It's irrelevant to measure performance for a debug build. It will certainly change drastically with optimizations enabled.

Comment: locking a mutex is overhead that you want to avoid as much as possible (but of course not more than that). Sloppy speaking if you have more locks & mutexes you have more overhead

Comment: Dynamically allocating a scope guard (such as `Guard`) defeats the exception safety they provide. Consider using braces to limit their scope instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I did a release build. Things get.. interesting: 

no thread 0.16 /
5 locks 0.18 /
1 lock 0.14 /
no locks 0.04 /

So using 5 locks actually became slower than not using multithreading at all. Which makes some sense: code is basically a worst case scenario of concurrent writes.

Comment: Setting up the locks could be part of the reason. Try a larger data set if possible.

Comment: You have almost no work done outside the locks.  This means that as soon as the thread is done with one lock it moves to the next attempt to lock.  You may as well be single threaded in your design;  and it seems your release build demonstrates that

Comment: @UKMonkey, it is a worst case scenario type of test that I was going for but what confuses me would be that, if I were using many individual locks it would be possible for the threads to only pause when both where in the same index. By using just one big lock it happens on access instead. So it should be slower, but the opposite is what is happening in practice.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the answer section is below ;)

Comment: @tobi303 Sometimes I get confused.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's the C++ part of SO;  answers are only put into answers once discussed sufficiently

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks for the replies, it completely answered my initial question!

Comment: You are missing another case: using a lockfree approach with compare and swap or other atomics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead of locking and unlocking a mutex is likely much greater than the cost of preforming a simple arithmetic operation on an `int`, which makes the individual locks case pretty much measure mutex overhead. Another way of looking at it, the cost of synchronization using this approach is greater than the time saved parallelizing.

Since you spend almost no time outside of the lock in the single lock case, all but one worker are waiting for the lock, meaning the result is approximately the sum of the single threaded approach, plus the mutex overhead.

It's *very* hard to come up with a representative model when measuring performances. What constitutes a "best solution" depends on many factors. What might be best in one case may not be ideal in another seemingly similar case. It's best to measure the actual application.

Comment: The cost of locking and unlocking the mutex is the same: you lock/unlock the mutex *once*. The lock granularity affects whether other threads get locked even though they want to access a different element in the vector. The problem can be related to cache invalidations: a thread that got the lock get his cache line invalidated due to another being able to modify it (although the elements are different: false sharing). A good way of testing this approach would be to pad the elements of the vector so that each one of them is placed in a different cache line.

Comment: See [identifying false sharing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, looking at your comment of

> no thread 0.16 / 5 locks 0.18 / 1 lock 0.14 / no locks 0.04

and your code, the "no thread" and "1 lock" are expected to give the same result.  This 0.2 difference is the same with your 5 locks.

Given that the values are ms, this could trivially be related to something else happening on your machine, there are after all, many more threads asking the OS for CPU time and memory bandwidth.

The 0.2ms difference could also be related to CPU cache, as well as a range of other things I'm not able to immediately think of, but my emphasis is that the ERROR of the test is unknown; and as with all statistics, it's an important thing to measure.

Comment: Yeah the differences are minuscule as I had not thought of turning optimization on when I first posted. To do it properly I'd have to substantially increase the workload so that circumstantial factors or initial setup costs get mitigated. As @FrançoisAndrieux pointed out most of time saved with parallelism was mitigated due to always being in critical sections and the time cost of the sync operation itself versus the work required.